# constructor inheritance with C++11 compiler is generating error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am trying to compile the following code (taken directly from wikipedia) to understand constructor inheritance in C++11 :

```
class BaseClass {
    public:
    BaseClass(int value);
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
    using BaseClass::BaseClass;
};
```

I am compiling this file as follows :

```
/usr/bin/g++-4.7 -c -std=c++11 file.cpp
```

But this is giving the following error :

```
error: ‘BaseClass::BaseClass’ names constructor
```

I do not know where am I going wrong

Comment: http://ideone.com/hDLJhN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheriting constructors were not supported in GCC until version 4.8.

[Source](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Answer (score 3):

According to [C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) inheriting constructors were not available until gcc 4.8.

I can confirm that with http://gcc.godbolt.org/ as

```
class BaseClass {
    public:
    BaseClass(int value);
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
    using BaseClass::BaseClass;
};

int main()
{
}
```

Compiles just fine with gcc 4.8.1([Live Example](http://goo.gl/Rts41t))